# 'gatsby-plugin-google-analytics' is not working for my gatsby-strapi website

Tags: google-analytics, gatsby

this is my code in gatsby-config.js

```
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: `title`,
    description: ``,
    author: `@Wavii`,
  },

  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-google-analytics`,
      options: {
        trackingId: "UA-XXXXXX-XX",
        // Defines where to place the tracking script - `true` in the head and `false` in the body
        head: true,
      },
    },
    `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `images`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/images`,
      },
    },
```

don't know why it is not working, it is not even showing any google analytics on my source code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you test it? Please note the plugin only works for production builds `$ gatsby build`

Answer (score 6):

use [gatsby-plugin-google-gtag](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-google-gtag/?=gtag) with the following configuration for the google analytics 4 support.
Put it at the top of the plugins list, and I was not able to get it to work without "anonymize_ip: true".

```
plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-google-gtag`,
      options: {
        trackingIds: [
          "GA-TRACKING_ID", // Google Analytics / GA
        ],
        pluginConfig: {
          head: true,
          anonymize_ip: true,
        },
      },
    },
    // other plugins
  ],
```

Comment: No words could explain how thankful i am for you answer

Answer (score 4):

I can't get it working in production either. I've also tried https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-gtag/ - which I hear is the "newer" way, and I can get some results using Helmet like so:

```
  <Helmet>
  <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXX-X"></script>
  <script type="application/ld+json">{`
      window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
      function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
      gtag('config', 'UA-XXX-X');
  `}</script>
  </Helmet>
```

... but I don't have it successfully testing in production yet. I've installed all the google analytics plugins and though debug works in the case of Helmet, I'm not really getting good results otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

For me it did not work because I was using ad blocker browser plugin, which was blocking all analytics data. After disabling the plugin everything worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

"**gatsby-plugin-google-analytics**" generate obsolete "ga"

switch to  "**gatsby-plugin-google-gtag**" is generate "gtag"

*reference*
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/migration